# Non Linear Regression Troubleshooting

Tags: r, nls, non-linear-regression

Following is an excerpt from my data set: relative frequency and size. As you can see from the open-circles, this is a Gaussian distribution. I am using the `nls` package in R to fit a nonlinear curve. 
My equation is [image: Gaussian]

or in plain text: `c * e^(-(x - z)^2/l)`

[image]

Here is how I got here

```
fit <- as.formula(y~c*(exp((-(x-z)^2/l))))
preview(fit_partial, data=mydata, start=list(c=0.005, x=mydata$x_values, z=130,l=2000))
```

The starting values seem reasonable. So I try to get a non-linear fit

```
nls_fit <- nls(fit, data=mydata, start=list(c=0.005, x=mydata$x_values, z=130, l=2000))
```

However, I'm thrown with an error

> Error in numericDeriv(form[[3L]], names(ind), env) : 
>   Missing value or an infinity produced when evaluating the model

This is likely because my starting values are poor. Something else must be the issue though. Appreciate any help.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. But I don't think `x` should be in your start list. If you use a formula with a `data=` parameter it will be able to find the values in the data.frame. You are not tying to estimate the values of `x`. Those are given.

Comment: @MrFlick Ok, I will work to add more to my example. Yes, I am not trying to predict x; x comes from my data set. If I remove x from the start list i get the error
``parameters without starting value in 'data': x``
I have a very tenuous grasp of programming and R in general; can you clarify what you meant?

Comment: I think this example is well-written, but it's hard to troubleshoot without understanding what your data looks like. Can you take a small sample of it, reproduce the issue on the sample, and share that sample data in your post (using a function such as `dput(my_data)`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, your only problem is including `x` in your list of parameters, which is confusing R (I can't *exactly* tell you why ... something about the fact that it's not actually a parameter of the model ...). `nls(fit, data=mydata, start=pars)` works fine for me.

Simulate data:

```
fit <- as.formula(y~c*(exp((-(x-z)^2/l))))
mydata <- data.frame(x=80:200)
pars <- list(c=0.005, z=130,l=2000)
set.seed(101)
mydata$y_det <- eval(fit[[3]],
                     env=c(pars,as.list(mydata)))
mydata$y <- rnorm(nrow(mydata),mean=mydata$y_det,sd=0.0002)
plot(y~x,data=mydata) ## check
```

Try original fit:

```
nls_fit <- nls(fit, data=mydata, start=c(pars,list(x=mydata$x)))
```

> Error in numericDeriv(form[[3L]], names(ind), env) : 
>     Missing value or an infinity produced when evaluating the model

Fit with parameters only (not `x`).

```
nls_fit <- nls(fit, data=mydata, start=pars)
lines(mydata$x,predict(nls_fit),col=2)
coef(nls_fit)
##           c            z            l 
## 4.963097e-03 1.302308e+02 2.035007e+03
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent solution. I was including x in the list of start parameters which was the source of the error. I followed your example and achieved similar results to your last figure (only with my real data).